# Visual Studio recognize my javascript files as typescript files and cause the code to break

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Just a few minutes ago I installed an extension for console logging using the `clg` and `tab` key shortcut. after the reload, my javascript files has the TS icon on the left bar and stopped recognizing keywords like `require`, `exports` and I have no idea how to solve it. How can I stop this weird behavior and continue working on my node app? (That's why I'm using require and exports, I'm working on a Node app for learning porpuses) Thanks.

Comment: what is the extension you installed ?

Comment: check if your JavaScript files have `.js` or `.ts` extension. TS uses `import` instead of `require` afaik

Comment: @menkr it doesn't matter. In VSC the JS intellisense is powered by the TS compiler. There are several ways to disable it, or OP could just npm install the nodejs typings.